# How we can give access or user permissions to a google docs link to share with others with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-docs-api

I am trying to give user permissions to google docs file using php with google docs api but I am getting scopes error and permissions error. It is giving errors while using insert and create permissions methods.
can you please share me the code, how to give user permission to the google docs file to share with others using PHP code and which type of scopes and services I have to use.

```
$fileId = $file->getId();
$role = 'writer';
$userEmail = 'user@gmail.com';
$fileId = $file->getId();

$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
  'type' => 'user',
  'role' => $role,
  'emailAddress' => $userEmail
));

$request = $service->permissions->create(
  $fileId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id')
);
```

getting is error-

```
An error occurred: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

This is my file-

```
<?php 
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes([
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY]);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
    }
}
$fileId = $file->getId();
// printf("%s",$fileId);

$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
  $newPermission->setEmailAddress('user@gmail.com');
  $newPermission->setType('user');
  $newPermission->setRole('writer');
  try {
    return $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  return NULL;
```

Comment: _"share me the code"_  is not a valid question. This isn't a free coding/code sharing service. Share all details about your current issue instead (like exactly what errors you get, when you do exactly what) and we can see if we can help from there. The title asks about sharing, but in the question you mention that you get errors for insert/create. Which is it? One question should concentrate on one specific issue. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @M.Eriksson what is your issue with the current code presented?    Inserting permissions is how you share a file in Google drive.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the full error message you are getting. As well as the authorization code just so i can see what scope you are using.

Comment: @DaImTo - I never said I had an issue with the code. I said that the question is lacking specifics since they have omitted the actual error messages they get, and when they get them (since they mention "sharing" in the title but "insert and create" in the question.)

Comment: Actually invalid_scope is a common Google api error that should be enough information to answer the question.   Not sure what you mean by **multiple different things**   Sharing a file using create permissions is a single thing this developer is trying to accomplish.   Where does **multiple** come into play?

Comment: @DaImTo, I have edited my question I have used the same scopes you have shared with me.But it still showing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [permissions create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) method requires one of the following scopes.

[image]

If you are getting a scope error make sure to check which scopes you are authorizing the user with.   Also if you have changed the scope in your code make sure to request authorization of the user again you don't want to be running on an outdated access token with your old permissions.

If we check your code

```
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY]);
```

You appear to have all of the scopes added. my guess is though that you ordinally only had DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY you ran your app once and authorized the user.  At which point your code saved the users credetinals within tokenPath.   So even though you have added new scopes your app has not requested the additional permissions from the user.  Delete the file in tokenPath  and then your app will request authorization again.

A  permissions error is something else. In order to insert the permissions the user you are logged in with must be the owner of the file only they can insert permissions.

## google docs link to share

If you are trying to create the share like that can be created in Google drive web application unfortunately that is not possible with the API.   Adding permissions to the file for the user will just mean that this user will have access to it in their google drive account.

As this is a Google dock you can use the webview link this will allow the user to open the file directly in their google docs account.

Comment: @DalmTo, can you please explain me in detail how we can use webview link to share my google docs with other users so that they can see my google docs without requesting access. It would be a great help if you could share me the code. I want to do it with PHP code. Please provide me with PHP code. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: @DalmTo, I have used the above scopes, then also the error is not resolving.

Comment: you need to insert permission as you are doing now then do a file.get will get you a WebView link for the user.   trying requesting authorization of the user again make sure you are seeing the correct scope in the consent screen.    you don't need my code yours should be fine

Comment: @DalmTo, Can you please ellaborate on webview link as I am not getting your point.

Comment: Check the [file object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) for webviewlink.   Its just a link to the file that when clicked on will open the document in the google docs application for the user if they have permissions set.

Comment: Please read my update on my answer on how to fix your scope issue you need to delete the file in tokenPath  and run your app again.